# Loading a kernel module (snd-aloop) multiple times

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to load "snd-aloop" in order to get multiple device nodes at the end like:

/dev/snd/xxx0

/dev/snd/xxx1

...

/dev/snd/xxxN

(How)Can I do it with simple modprobe command (Ubuntu 16.04) and some helper commands if needed? Need the exact steps to do it...

If NOT, (how) can I wrap with some C code the "snd-aloop" kernel driver a bit and spawn multiple instance of it? Need exact kernel C APIs and some sample code...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you cannot load the multiple instances of the same kernel module.

You can create multiple "devices" by calling device creation APIs. For example, netdev, char_dev,.... whatever you want.

Any specific reason to do this? from single kernel module, creating multiple devices are way more simpler. If you want to create the devices on-demand, use ioctl() or proc whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, correct, I cannot execute modprobe on snd-aloop multiple times.


_italic_You can create multiple "devices" by calling device creation APIs. For example, netdev, char_dev,.... whatever you want._italic_


Please, give me a written example how to attack snd-aloop to create multiple instances of it. What would be the result?

Comment: _italic_Any specific reason to do this? from single kernel module, creating multiple devices are way more simpler. If you want to create the devices on-demand, use ioctl() or proc whatever you want._italic_

Because I want to use snd-aloop and its code as it is:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/drivers/aloop.c

If it is not possible, please give me a written example how to modify it in order to have multiple ALSA devices like:
/dev/snd/pcmXXX1
/dev/snd/pcmXXX2
...
/dev/snd/pcmXXX3

Comment: I checked the source code - I am not familiar with this loopback sound card driver but what I can understand are:


1) alsa_card_loopback_init is initializing the driver. As you can see, based on SNDRV_CARDS, it loops and register the platform drivers. Can you check SNDDRV_CARDS and enable array? What is the number of devices?


2) After platform driver is registered, kernel will call probe() API to detect the devices. loopback_probe(). Here you can check how many times it is getting called after increasing the number of "enable" devices.